# Get post types based on taxonomy slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

In short,
If I have a taxonomy slug 'category' or 'post_tag', and I don't know which post-types have this taxonomy.

So how i know all post-types which have this taxonomy?

Thanks

Comment: you can use [new WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: but if I don't have any detail about post_type, Then wp_query is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I got the solution.**

I have slug of taxonomy/tag only - 'post_tag'

For get the Post-Types which have 'post_tag' taxonomy/tag

```
$post_types = get_taxonomy( 'post_tag' )->object_type;
```

That-sit, i got the post-types by slug of taxonomy/tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching the posts of a post-type assigned to any category or tags, you can use the following new WP_Query function:

For category taxonomy:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post_type_slug', 'category_name' => 'category_slug_name', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC');
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

For tags:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post_type_slug', 'tag' => 'tag_name', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC');
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

After writing the query, loop the posts:

```
if($query->have_posts()):
   while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
       echo get_the_title();
       echo get_the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Please get my point.

if I don't have post-type slug, I have only slug of taxonomy/tag.
for this situation, How can I get Post-types which have taxonomy/slug which i have.